# How does std::sort implement the swap operation using iterators only?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

How can I implement for instance the following

```
template <typename ITERATOR> void Swap (ITERATOR a, ITERATOR b) {
  ...
}
```

so that Swap(a, b) swaps the values pointed at by a and b.
In other words: How can I create a third variable without knowing the data type?

Comment: You mean `std::swap`, not `std::sort`, right?

Comment: Well, these are just examples. I want to do some re-arrangement/re-assignment of a container, where I only pass the iterators and I need some temporary variables.

Comment: @juanchopanza: No, I don't think he does mean that.  The question doesn't even make sense if you replace `std::sort` with `std::swap`, because `std::swap` doesn't work with iterators.  It would just swap the iterators themselves, not the values they point to, and that's clearly not what the OP is going for.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I see. The question just seemed so detatched from it's body that I got confused. First a specific question about `std::sort` implementation then a more general one swapping...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I create a third variable without knowing the data type?

Use `std::iterator_traits<ITERATOR>::value_type`

Answer (score 7):

There is [`iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) just for that job:

```
std::iter_swap(a, b);
```

Also if you can use c++11 you can use `decltype`:

```
std::remove_reference<decltype(*a)>::type c = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = c;
```

Answer (score 4):

In C++11, the type is `std::remove_reference<decltype(*a)>::type`, but for declaring a variable, you would use `auto`.

In C++03, the most reliable way to infer the type of any arbitrary expression is through another template:

```
// NOTE: This is for illustration only. If you are simply swapping
// values, use 'std::swap' instead of this, since that is specialised
// for many types to avoid unnecessary copy-assignment.
template <typename T> void value_swap(T & a, T & b) {
    T t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}

template <typename I> void iterator_swap(I a, I b) {
    value_swap(*a, *b);
}
```

Alternatively, for well-behaved iterators (including pointers and standard iterators), the type is available as `std::iterator_traits<ITERATOR>::value_type`. This won't work if someone has written their own iterator type without either providing the nested types that the default `iterator_traits` requires or specialising `iterator_traits` for it.

Some compilers provide non-standard extensions similar to `decltype`; for example GCC provides `typeof`. You could use such a thing if you don't need your code to be portable.

By the way, your particular function already exists as `std::iter_swap`.

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename ITERATOR> void Swap (ITERATOR a, ITERATOR b) {
  using std::swap;
  swap(*a,*b);
}
```

Comment: quite, but not completely. `using std::swap; swap(*a, *b);` because user types are not required to specialize `std::swap`, they might simply provide a `swap` function within their own namespace and rely on ADL to pick it up.

Answer (score 2):

The iterator has a so called trait defining it's value type.

```
        iterator_traits<ITERATOR>::value_type temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = temp;
```